# Cannot use unnest_tokens in R

Tags: r

I am trying to solve the question number four in https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/text-mining.html.

The code I'm using is below

```
words <- gutenberg_metadata[2] %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

However, for some reason I get the following error

```
Error in check_input(x) : Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
```

Why isn't unnest_tokens working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(tidytext)

gutenbergr::gutenberg_metadata[2] %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = title)
```

The input should be `title` (the column name) and not text.